# Laravel: How to set value of Checkbox from database

Tags: laravel, checkbox

The checkbox does not take the value from the database. Help please. Thank you.

**edit.blade.php**

```php
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" class="" id="onloan" 
         value="{{ $item->onloan }}">
  <label for="onloan">On Loan</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `checked` property of `input` element. 
`<input type="checkbox" class="" id="onloan" value="1" {{ $item->onloan == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>`

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but really sorry I cannot Vote Up yet. Maybe you can write it in the answer and I'll select it as the answer?

Comment: @GhanuBha give your comment as an answer, so that it can be acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `checked` property to check of `input` checkbox element.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="" id="onloan" value="1" {{ $item->onloan == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" id="onloan" value="{{ $item->onloan }}" {{$item->onloan == 1 ? 'checked' : ''}}>
    <label for="onloan">On Loan</label>
</div>
```